# Why this method has no definition in my IDE?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am doing android programming in xamarin, visual studio using `c#` language.
I want to write the following:

```
Spinner myspinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.myspinner);
string text = myspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I am getting an error that `getselecteditem()` is not defined. What can I do ?

Comment: What is `spinner2`. Please give more code/context when asking such.

Comment: It is the name of the Spinner. I changed it to "myspinner" to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
Spinner myspinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.myspinner);
string text = myspinner.SelectedItem.toString();
```